# jPlist plugin - how to reinit plugin after html change

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jplist

I am using [this](http://jplist.com/) plugin for pagination and sorting. Plugin works well, but i've noticed that i have problem. Content that is searchable is changed 4 times, i am using ajax call to split big amount of data into parts. So content is changed 4 times - i'm adding new content 4 times.
And jPlist plugin oes crazy. I have tried to add new items using [Add Range of Items Using API](http://jplist.com/documentation/api-add-range-of-items) but this seems not to work.
I'm looking for a solution, how can i reinit this plugin - so he can take new content into account.
If i simple run this plugin when i'm fetching data from ajax call, there are issues with plugin.
The datatables plugin has very nice option [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())

*When you perform an action such as adding or deleting a row, changing the sorting, filtering or paging characteristics of the table you'll want DataTables to update the display to reflect these changes. This function is provided for that purpose.*

Right now i need to find a way, if it's possible to do something similar in jplist plugin.

I know that i didnt show any code, beacuse i use have basic code from jplist docs, and ajax is very simple - it ask API for new data. And it's done 4 times as i said, and results are added to content by jquery html() function.

Thanks for any advice.